# Microsoft band heart sensor sampling rate and event control

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I have successfully obtained data from the Heart Rate Sensor and the Heart Rate Quality Sensor using the following code:-

```
 IEnumerable<TimeSpan> supportedHeartBeatReportingIntervals = bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.SupportedReportingIntervals;
 bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.ReportingInterval = supportedHeartBeatReportingIntervals.First<TimeSpan>();
..... [other not relevant code excluded]

bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.ReadingChanged += (s, args) => { hrdt = args.SensorReading.HeartRate; };
{
    await bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.StartReadingsAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    await bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.StopReadingsAsync();
    dsphr = hrdt.ToString();
}
bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.ReadingChanged += (s, args) =>  qltyhr = string.Format("{0}",args.SensorReading.Quality);
```

This code is working nicely and here is some sample from an output file I am writing

> Richard;;8:48:04 AM;64
>
> Richard;Acquiring;8:48:19 AM;64
>
> Richard;Acquiring;8:48:35 AM;64
>
> Richard;Acquiring;8:48:50 AM;64
>
> Richard;Acquiring;8:49:05 AM;64

etc - records all showing acquiring - the 70 change in heart rate came when the device was acquiring heart rate and not from a reading.

> Richard;Acquiring;8:52:08 AM;70

Record format is my name, sensor quality, time and then heart rate. ";" is used as a field delimiter in a flat file

I then repeated the test but this time using the band in "run" workout mode and the data results are as follows:

> Richard;Locked;9:15:32 AM;57
>
> Richard;Acquiring;9:15:47 AM;67
>
> Richard;Locked;9:16:03 AM;64
>
> Richard;Acquiring;9:16:18 AM;62
>
> Richard;Locked;9:16:33 AM;72

etc same sort of story

> Richard;Locked;9:24:40 AM;73
>
> Richard;Locked;9:24:55 AM;72

Help!! Here are a few questions:

- Understanding the "battery life" issue that is being managed by the different modes - what I would like to do in an ideal world would be to set my own sampling rate that woke up and locked the sensor for the reading and then made it go back to sleep again to save battery. I am guessing this is impossible as it is one imagines a firmware issue. Am I correct? If not how do I do it?
- If I cannot have the ideal - what I would like to do is to be able to switch sampling mode from a program and NOT by pushing a button on the Band. So I could then undertake a "burst sample" as in an exercise event on a timed basis and the background check carry on for the rest of the time to conserve battery.
  Can I do this and if so how?
- What is the relevance of setting the Band Reporting Interval - is there anything I should change here that would help control when the sensor is on and locked (Exercise Mode vs when it is off and acquiring (Normal Mode). If so how should I be coding this? From my own tests it looks like the Mode of the sensor has nothing to do with the reporting interval - but am I wrong?
- Failing that is there any documentation that explains how this sampling is working in the finest detail? I have spent considerable time searching the web and found the following:
- Normal mode seems to sample 3 or 4 times and hour
- Normal mode wakes up into active mode if the band detects significant movement - for example I went for a run this morning with the band in normal mode and it work itself up into exercise mode once it worked what I was doing - clever and the more I think about it useful.
- Even Exercise mode has some "acquiring" events - but these seem to be predictive as well as just past values - if I cannot measure on an intensive basis - I would like to know what is kicking in the heart prediction so I can work out whether it is meaningful or not

The SDK Documentation does not give this level of detail, and I really cannot find another way of finding out ... so Help!

I hope the code and data formats are readable in this post as it is the first time I posted on this forum - so please forgive me if I have "pushed the wrong button" on including the text!

Thank you for any help or insight you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is how the heart rate subscription works in all versions of the Microsoft Band SDK.

1) When you subscribe, you turn the heart rate gathering on, unless it is already on due to an activity or the passive heart rate monitoring of the Band's firmware.

2) When you unsubscribe, you turn the heart rate gathering off, unless the firmware is also gathering heart rate data due to the same as mentioned above.

3) The rate of the heart rate subscription is 1 hz and cannot be changed.

4) The data returned from this subscription is the heart rate calculated by the Band, not a direct reading. Thus Aquiring vs Locked represents how accurate the Band thinks its reading is and will be more effected by how the user is wearing the band (tighter is better for this) than what activity the user is doing with the band

Thus, to conserve battery life and get the data in bursts, all you have to do is subscribe, get as many events as you desire, and then unsubscribe.

The other data you are getting from documentation refers to how the heart rate is used internally, not how it is exposed by the SDK.